# Cannot upgrade to Symfony 3 because of a dependency

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-process

I'm trying to upgrade from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3, but I cannot update it from Composer.

I get this error :

```
hellogerard/jobby dev-master requires symfony/process ^2.7 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v2.7.0 ... blabla bla v2.8.2]
```

When I look the composer.json file of this library I need, I see this :

```
  "require": {
    (...)
    "symfony/process": "^2.7"
  },
```

You can find the composer file of Jobby here : https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby/blob/master/composer.json

The problem is that in Symfony 3, the symfony/process version is 3.0, and because of the "^2.7" on Jobby's composer.json, I cannot get it. I know that there is no backwards compatibilities problems with symfony/process, so how can I do to fix / ignore that problem ?

Regards

Comment: Create a fork of `hellogerard/jobby` with fixed dependency

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm working on it

Comment: FYI, I created [a pull request](https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby/pull/49) to allow Symfony 3 components (you can use my fork of the repo until the PR is merged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own fork and make a pull request on the base repository.

If there is no BC-break using the requested package with `symfony/process:3.0`,
just change the package version from `^2.7` to `^3.0` or `>=2.7` in your fork's composer.json.

**EDIT**
Then, tell composer to use your fork for installations, like this :

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/yourusername/jobby"
    }
],
"require": {
    "hellogerard/jobby": "dev-master"
}
```

See [VCS Repositories documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

Comment: Never publish a temporary fork on packagist. You can directly hint composer to your fork.